# Must declare the scalar variable "@status" "User defined table type"

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-types

I am using user-defined table types like below. Note , Please i am generating my query string dynamically and execute the string at the end. You may notice some quotes

```
      ALTER PROCEDURE MyPROC
        @phoneNo nvarchar(30) = null,
        @status dbo.StatusViewTableType READONLY

        AS 
        BEGIN
     if(@option = 1)
    begin
      set @sql = 'SELECT   c.id,c.name,c.NewIc,c.OldIc,c.Title,c.nationality,c.CreatedDate,c.companyNo,c.NonIc,c.Email
                        FROM    customer c WITH (NOLOCK)
                        left outer join
                        dbo.Address with(nolock) on c.id =  dbo.Address.CustomerID 
                        left outer join dbo.ContactNo on c.id=dbo.ContactNo.CustomerID
                        WHERE     (c.id > 0) and ('


        if @oldIC <>'' and @phoneNo=''
            set @sql = @sql + ' (oldic ='''+ @oldIC + ''' )or'

        if @newIC <>'' and @phoneNo=''
            set @sql = @sql + ' (newIC ='''+ @newIC + ''' )or'

        if @companyno <>'' and @phoneNo=''
            set @sql = @sql + ' (companyno ='''+ @companyno + ''' )or'

        if @nonic <>'' and @phoneNo=''
            set @sql = @sql + ' (nonic ='''+ @nonic + ''' )or'

        If @phoneNo <>'' and @oldIC = '' and @newIC = '' and @companyno = '' and @nonic ='' 
        begin
            set @sql ='SELECT     c.id,c.name,c.NewIc,c.OldIc,c.Title,c.nationality,c.CreatedDate,c.companyNo,c.NonIc,c.Email
        FROM         dbo.Customer WITH (NOLOCK) c INNER JOIN
                              dbo.ContactNo WITH (NOLOCK)  ON c.id = dbo.ContactNo.CustomerID
        where   ContactNo = '''+ @phoneNo + ''' and  dbo.ContactNo.Contactability in (SELECT s.status   from  ' + [@status] + '  AS s ) '
        end
        if  @phoneNo='' 
        begin
        set @sql = Left(@sql,Len(@sql)-2)
        set @sql = @sql + ')'
        set @sql = @sql + '  and ( dbo.Address.Contactable in (SELECT  s.status   from ' + [@status] + '   AS s) or  dbo.ContactNo.Contactability in (SELECT  s.status from ' + [@status] + ' AS s) )'
        end 
print @sql

exec (@sql)
end
```

END

In my backend code I pass the parameters like below:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = null;
SqlCommand myCommand = null;
SqlDataReader myReader = null;
myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
myCommand.CommandText = "GETCUSTOMER";
myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
myCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
SqlParameter parameter;

int l = ids.FirstOrDefault().Length;
if (ids.FirstOrDefault().Length > 0)
{
    if (useDataTable)
    {
        parameter = myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", CreateDataTable(ids));
    }
    else
    {
        parameter = myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", CreateSqlDataRecords(ids));
    }

    parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
    parameter.TypeName = "dbo.StatusViewTableType";   
}

myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@phoneNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar));    
myCommand.Parameters["@phoneNo"].Value = phoneNo;
```

I am having an issue with the parameter `@status`. Its not recognized in the stored procedure.

It's throwing an exception:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@status".

Below is my `StatusViewTAbleType`.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[StatusViewTableType] AS TABLE(
    [Status] [int] NOT NULL
)
GO
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please review all of the edits I made to your post before making further changes. It's always good practice to present your questions in the best manner possible, otherwise they won't be well received. I rolled back your edit as I spent a few minutes formatting the question for you, so re-apply your changes in line with my edit.

Comment: Sorry sir my cquery is generate dynamically. Like above.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using a table-valued parameter in a fully qualified object name, then you have to enclose it in brackets, i.e. instead of `@Status.status` it should be `[@Status].status` or use an alias.

You can recreate this quite simply:

```
DECLARE @P TABLE (ID INT);
SELECT @P.ID FROM @P;
```

Which throws the error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@P".

I also don't think you are using the paramters properly, I think your procedure should be:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE MyPROC
    @phoneNo nvarchar(30) = NULL,
    @status dbo.StatusViewTableType READONLY

AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT    * 
    FROM    dbo.Customer WITH (NOLOCK)  
            INNER JOIN dbo.ContactNo WITH (NOLOCK)  
                ON dbo.Customer.id = dbo.ContactNo.CustomerID
    WHERE   ContactNo = @phoneNo
    AND     dbo.ContactNo.Contactability IN (SELECT s.status FROM @status AS s);

END
```

Finally, I would **strongly** advise against [using `SELECT *` in production code](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)

---

**EDIT**

With regard to your dynamic SQL problem, use [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) which will allow you to use parameters, so instead of something like:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT A, B, C FROM T WHERE 1 = 1',
        @P NVARCHAR(10) = 'X';
IF @P <> '' 
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND A = ''' + @P + '''';
    
EXEC(@SQL);
```

You would use

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT A, B, C FROM T WHERE 1 = 1',
        @P NVARCHAR(10) = 'X';
IF @P <> '' 
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND A = @P';
    
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@P NVARCHAR(10), @P;
```

So you are passing @P as a parameter to the query. This should solve all your single quote issues

Comment: @ Mr Gareth pls how do i acheive this in an sql string like the one from my procedure above. I am really having a hard time with this.

Comment: @MR gareth .It looks like sp_executesql  what i am looking for. howveer, when i run its asking fo ra @statement parameter Which is not there. Please can you help me with my parameters .`@id bigint = 0,
@oldIC nvarchar(200) = '',
@newIC nvarchar(200) = '',
@companyno nvarchar(100) = '',
@nonic nvarchar(100) = '',
@phoneNo nvarchar(100) = '',
@option int = 0,
@sql nvarchar(1000) = null,
@status dbo.StatusViewTableType READONLY` .?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you have used unwanted single quotes. Try this.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Myproc @phoneNo NVARCHAR(30) = NULL,
                       @status  dbo.STATUSVIEWTABLETYPE READONLY
AS
  BEGIN
      SELECT *
      FROM   dbo.Customer WITH (NOLOCK)
             INNER JOIN dbo.ContactNo WITH (NOLOCK)
                     ON dbo.Customer.id = dbo.ContactNo.CustomerID
      WHERE  ContactNo = @phoneNo
             AND dbo.ContactNo.Contactability IN (SELECT status
                                                  FROM   @status)
  END
```

Comment: Sorry sir , for got to mentioned . The reason for the single quotes was my query is dynamically created. Please see my proc again.

Comment: @NuruSalihu - As garethD mentioned you need to enclose @status with brackets like `..select [@Status].status from..`

Comment: Ok i am trying now. tq

Comment: I am getting invalid column name [@status]. Please i am generating the query string dymaically and then executing the string at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic SQL does not recognize variables outside of it's scope. That's the reason it is erroring out.